# How to make smaller items setting rows themselves?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to create CSS classes that will allow me to store widgets' grid layout configuration in DB and to be dynamic.

My goal is to have reusable classes to auto position widgets according to order in HTML and size defined by a class. The problem is the small widget needs to have a defined row value in order to be placed correctly.

My goal is to achieve the following layout:

[image: Expected layout]

I created the following HTML and CSS:

```
<div class="widgets-grid">
  <div class="widgets-grid__widget widget--medium">1</div>
  <div class="widgets-grid__widget widget--small">2</div>
  <div class="widgets-grid__widget widget--small">3</div>
  <div class="widgets-grid__widget">4</div>
  <div class="widgets-grid__widget">5</div>
  <div class="widgets-grid__widget">6</div>
  <div class="widgets-grid__widget">7</div>
</div>
```

```
.widgets-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  column-gap: 17px;
  row-gap: 15px;

  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;

  .widgets-grid__widget {
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    grid-column: span 4;
    grid-row: span 2;
  }

  .widgets-grid__widget:nth-child(odd) {
    grid-column: 1 / 3; // left column
  }

  .widgets-grid__widget:nth-child(even) {
    grid-column: 3 / 5; // right column
  }

  .widgets-grid__widget.widget--small {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    height: auto;

    // my hack
    &:nth-child(odd) {
      grid-row: 1; // manual positon :(
    }
    &:nth-child(even) {
      grid-row: 2; // manual positon :(
    }
  }

  .widgets-grid__widget.widget--medium {
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
  }
}
```

So if no additional class provided widget will have standard size 2x2. There are 2 other sizes: `.widget--medium` (1 col and 2 rows) and `.widget--small` (1 row and 1 col).

I created a hack to achieve my goal, but it won't work if I will have small widgets in 2'nd and 3'rd rows...

```
// my hack
&:nth-child(odd) {
  grid-row: 1; // manual position :(
}
&:nth-child(even) {
  grid-row: 2; // manual position :(
}
```

I tried also `grid-row: auto` but then widget 4 is broken.

[image: Broken widget 4]

Please advise!

Try on StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-5o8cxz

Comment: Have you tried a `grid-auto-flow: dense` on the grid parent?

Comment: @PsiKai my hero, it's working like charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific case, grid is trying to keep all the elements in document order, thus it is creating new rows in order to accommodate the extra space needed.

That is the default behavior of grid, but you can override this by setting the parent grid-container to have the following property:

```
grid-auto-flow: dense
```

This will allow grid items to be displayed in the first available open grid, and will allow them to be out of document order if your layout needs it.

[Grid flow docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow)

A really great youtube content creator Kevin Powell can teach you all of the really handy, lesser known properties of flex and grid.  Highly recommended to anyone trying to get better at webpage layouts:

[Masonry Layout](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KrPz_wmBsAE)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use `grid-areas` to define exactly where you want elements to go in the grid, and assign the appropriate `grid-area` to each class.  See grid-areas docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas)

Something like this:

```css
.parent {
  height: 500px;
  width: 800px;
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3,  1fr);
  grid-template-areas: "one two four" "one two five" "three two six";
}

.parent > * {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.c1 {
  grid-area: one;
}

.c2 {
  grid-area: two;
}

.c3 {
  grid-area: three;
 }

.c4 {
  grid-area: four;
  
 }

.c5 {
  grid-area: five;
 }

.c6 {
  grid-area: six;
 }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class='c1'></div>
   <div class='c2'></div>
   <div class='c3'></div>
   <div class='c4'></div>
   <div class='c5'></div>
   <div class='c6'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @PrzemekPobuta  Check out this implementation, it's much cleaner and easier to modularize for your kind of grid layout.

Comment: I think the solution with `grid-auto-flow: dense` is good enough. `grid-template-areas` is not dynamic and I need a solution where I can have rows based on how many widgets there are. I tested  `grid-auto-flow: dense` and work in every row, so thank you very much!

Comment: Sounds good.  I'll leave this answer up for anybody in the future who may face a similar problem.

Comment: Please add the answer for `grid-auto-flow: dense` so I can mark it as accepted and vote for it. Once again, thank you!